# Backoff delay duration less than minimum value

Tags: flutter

Back off delay duration less than minimum value in flutter download .
Notification keeps on loading

Answer (score -1):

This is caused by the limitation of FlutterDownloaderPlugin.java
The minimum value is 10 seconds .i.e. The time gap between two consecutive downloads.
Set a duration of 10 seconds for the next download to occur.

The issue only occurs in andorid simulator, but it works in real device.